# change server selection after installing phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, lighttpd

After reading a bit I installed phpmyadmin on an Ubuntu server (14.04) with

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

In the installation configuration screens I was asked whether I wanted to use apache2 or lighttpd servers. I selected lighttpd and the installation went on smoothly. I noticed that it still (aparently) installed apache2 server.

Now, reading more on the topic, I feel more confortable if I could use phpmyadmin on apache2 server instead of on lighttpd. Is there a way to change this selection now, without uninstalling and reinstalling again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possibilities about being prompted for a webserver to use; before `apt-get` downloads any files it resolves conflicts and installs dependencies -- if you don't have a webserver installed it will prompt you to install one (or do so automatically). The other time it asks you about which webserver to use is after downloading and during configuration; if you have more than one webserver installed, you're prompted for which you want to work with phpMyAdmin. You can pick more than one here, by the way.

To configure phpMyAdmin to work with Apache instead, you can use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```